# LateInitializationError: Field 'questionsSnapshot' has not been initialized when fetching the data from Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_testtt/models/question_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_testtt/screens/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_testtt/screens/reusable_widgets/quiz_play_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_testtt/services/database.dart';

class GameQuiz extends StatefulWidget {
  final String quizId;
  GameQuiz(this.quizId);
  //const GameQuiz({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GameQuiz> createState() => _GameQuizState();
}

int total = 0;
int _correct = 0;
int _incorrect = 0;
int _notAttempted = 0;

class _GameQuizState extends State<GameQuiz> {
   late QuerySnapshot questionsSnapshot;
   DatabaseService databaseService = new DatabaseService();
  QuestionModel getQuestionModelFromDatasnapshot(DocumentSnapshot questionSnapshot) {
    QuestionModel questionModel = new QuestionModel();

    questionModel.question = questionSnapshot["question"];

    List<String> options = [
      questionSnapshot["option1"],
      questionSnapshot["option2"],
      questionSnapshot["option3"],
      questionSnapshot["option4"],
    ];
    options.shuffle();

    questionModel.option1 = options[0];
    questionModel.option2 = options[1];
    questionModel.option3 = options[2];
    questionModel.option4 = options[3];
    questionModel.correctOption = questionSnapshot["option1"];
    questionModel.answered = false;

    return questionModel;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("${widget.quizId}");
  
    databaseService.getQuizData(widget.quizId).then((value) {
      questionsSnapshot = value;
      _notAttempted = 0;
      _correct = 0;
      _incorrect = 0;
      total = questionsSnapshot.docs.length;

      print("$total this is total");
      setState(() {});
    });
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('QUIZ'),
          backgroundColor: background,
          shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              questionsSnapshot.docs.length==0?
                   const SizedBox.shrink()
                  : ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: questionsSnapshot.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return QuizPlayTile(
                          questionModel:getQuestionModelFromDatasnapshot(questionsSnapshot.docs[index]), 
                          index: index,
                        );
                      },
                    )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class _questionsSnapshot {
}

class QuizPlayTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final QuestionModel questionModel;
  final int index;
  QuizPlayTile({required this.questionModel, required this.index});

  @override
  State<QuizPlayTile> createState() => _QuizPlayTileState();
}

class _QuizPlayTileState extends State<QuizPlayTile> {
  String optionSelected = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(widget.questionModel.question),
          SizedBox(
            height: 4,
          ),
          OptionTile(
            correctAnswer: widget.questionModel.option1,
            description: widget.questionModel.option1,
            option: "A",
            OptionSelected: optionSelected,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 4,
          ),
          OptionTile(
            correctAnswer: widget.questionModel.option1,
            description: widget.questionModel.option2,
            option: "B",
            OptionSelected: optionSelected,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 4,
          ),
          OptionTile(
            correctAnswer: widget.questionModel.option1,
            description: widget.questionModel.option3,
            option: "C",
            OptionSelected: optionSelected,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 4,
          ),
          OptionTile(
            correctAnswer: widget.questionModel.option1,
            description: widget.questionModel.option4,
            option: "D",
            OptionSelected: optionSelected,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is a part of the mobile application written in flutter.
I have been getting the following error:
Exception has occurred.
LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'questionsSnapshot' has not been initialized.)

Answer (score 0):

You declared `questionsSnapshot` as `late` here:

```
late QuerySnapshot questionsSnapshot;
```

Using `late` is a promise that you'll give `questionsSnapshot` a value before you ever try to read it. But since you need to read the value from Firestore, which is an asynchronous operation, your `build` code uses `questionsSnapshot` before it's ever set in `initState`.

The proper solution is to make `questionsSnapshot` optional:

```
QuerySnapshot? questionsSnapshot;
```

And then handle the case that it's `null`  in `build`:

```
body: Container(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      questionsSnapshot == null || questionsSnapshot!.docs.length==0 ?
        ...
```